# value not pushed in global array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

pushing singleCompany object in company array, but after all process console.log company array it gives empty array. what is the error which is not adding singleCompany to company array.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

let company = [];

for (var x = 50000; x < 50003; x++) {
  let url = `https://scci.com.pk/member-details/?id=A-${x}`;





    rp(url).then((html) => {
      let $ = cheerio.load(html);

      let name = $("tr:eq(1)").text().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
      let email = $("label[for='cp_email']").parent().next().text();
      let ptcl = $("label[for='cp_phone']").parent().next().text();
      let mobile = $("label[for='cp_mobile']").parent().next().text();
      let singleCompany =
      {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        ptcl: ptcl,
        mobile: mobile
      }
      company.push(singleCompany);
    });

};
console.log(company)
```

Comment: *"... but after all process..."* Ah, but they haven't yet. The request is **asynchronous**. See the answers to the linked questions.

Comment: Here's one way you might do it: https://pastebin.com/42reMngB